# Why Request and Response blank in listener when run jmx via command line

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I run `JMX` via command line, After completion of test when I load `.JTL` file to any listener , I can see data only in tab "Sample Result". `Request` and `response` both blank. Am I missing any configuration?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Already added following in file **/bin/user.properties** :

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View results Tree` listener is used for debugging purpose only. You can configure your `user.properties` file to see the response and request. But it is highly discouraged.

In your `user.properties` file add these config:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
```

Then restart your JMeter and collect your jtl file from non gui mode and then open the jtl file in gui mode. You will see your request and response there.

**UPDATE:**
You can also try this when you running your test:

```
 ./jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -n -t your_test_plan.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Now when you extract your result.jtl file, you will see the request, response etc.

It is highly discouraged because it will save huge data when there are so many requests. I would prefer to use `Wireshark` for this purpose.

Comment: I just followed given step but still .jtl returns blank for request and response. Please see file here : http://prnt.sc/epveya

Comment: `./jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -n -t testplan.jmx -l result.jtl` pass these properties via -J command-line argument when run the test.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to give a space after `-J`.

```
./jmeter -J jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -J jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -J jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -J jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -J jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -J jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -n -t testplan.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Comment: Please consider that there might be more answers in the future, so which of the "several" other answers are you referring to. Use the link provided by "Share" beneath it. Also, in order to convince users of the usefulness of your delta-answerr, please explain the reason for the modification you propose. Try for [answer] and consider taking the [tour]. Also, you should give credit for the much older comment which provided this insight. And your post, with the improved formatting options an answer post provides, should make use of it.